# php model mvc, not saving data

Tags: php, model-view-controller

As you are, I am making a project using the view controller model in php and I am having the following problem when trying to enter a new user to the database, when I run the model that takes care of that task without the controller for example I made a file and i run it direct and it works fine and insert the user correctly but when i want to run it from the corresponding controller it doesn't work at all.

I do not understand what may be happening.

Controller:
class usuarioControlador extends usuarioModelo{

```
/*----- Controlador para agregar el usuario nuevo  -------*/
public function agregar_usuario_controlador(){
    // Limpiamos todos los valores que recibimos y los pasamos a variables usando el metodo del mainModel Limpiar_cadena
    $dni = mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_dni_reg']);
    $nombre=  mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_nombre_reg']);
    $apellido= mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_apellido_reg']);
    $telefono= mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_telefono_reg']);
    $direccion= mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_direccion_reg']);

    $usuario= mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_usuario_reg']);
    $email= mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_email_reg']);
    $clave1= mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_clave_1_reg']);
    $clave2= mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_clave_2_reg']);

    $privilegio=  mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_privilegio_reg']); 
    $rol=  mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_rol_reg']); 

  
            // lleno el array para mandar al modelo con los datos
            $datos_usuario_reg=[
                "DNI"=>$dni,
                "Nombre"=>$nombre,
                "Apellido"=>$apellido,
                "Telefono"=>$telefono,
                "Direccion"=>$direccion,
                "Email"=>$email,
                "Usuario"=>$usuario,
                "Clave"=>$clave1,
                "Estado"=>"Activa", // la cuenta por defecto se ingresa como activa.
                "Privilegio"=>$privilegio,
                "Rol"=>$rol
            ];

            // llamamos el modelo de agregar usuario
            $agregar_usuario=usuarioModelo::agregar_usuario_modelo($datos_usuario_reg);

            // verificamos que se haya ingresado el usuario nuevo
            if ($agregar_usuario->rowCount()==1) {
                $mensaje=[
                    "tipo_mensaje"=>"exito",
                    "tipo_frm"=>"add",
                    "cuerpo_mensaje"=>"OK",
                    "tiempoEspera"=>5000
                ];
            } else {
                $mensaje=[
                    "tipo_mensaje"=>"error",
                    "tipo_frm"=>"add",
                    "cuerpo_mensaje"=>"ERROR",
                    "tiempoEspera"=>5000
                ];
            }
            echo json_encode($mensaje);// convierto a json la alerta

}/* FIN Controlador Agregar Usuario*/
```

model:

```
class usuarioModelo extends mainModel{
 
/*----- Modelo para agregar el usuario nuevo  -------*/
static function agregar_usuario_modelo($datos){
    try{


        // ejecutarmos el modelo conectar, mandamos a preparar la consulta sql de insercion
        $sql= mainModel::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios(usuario_nombre, usuario_apellido, usuario_dni, usuario_usuario, usuario_clave, usuario_telefono, usuario_direccion, usuario_email, usuario_ctaestado, usuario_privilegios, usuario_idrol)
                                              VALUES (:Nombre, :Apellido, :Dni, :Usuario, :Clave, :Telefono, :Direccion, :Email, :Estado, :Privilegio, :Rol);");
        // pasamos los parametros
        $sql->bindParam("Dni",$datos['DNI']);
        $sql->bindParam("Nombre",$datos['Nombre']);
        $sql->bindParam("Apellido",$datos['Apellido']);
        $sql->bindParam("Telefono",$datos['Telefono']);
        $sql->bindParam("Direccion",$datos['Direccion']);
        $sql->bindParam("Email",$datos['Email']);
        $sql->bindParam("Usuario",$datos['Usuario']);
        $sql->bindParam("Clave",$datos['Clave']);
        $sql->bindParam("Estado",$datos['Estado']);
        $sql->bindParam("Privilegio",$datos['Privilegio']);
        $sql->bindParam("Rol",$datos['Rol']);

        $sql->execute();// ejecutamos la consulta
        return $sql;// devolvemos la consulta
     //   return 'exito';//TODO: CAMBIAR DESPUES O VER SI LO DEJO ASI

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

}// fin del modelo
```

Test Code:

$dni,
                "Nombre"=>$nombre,
                "Apellido"=>$apellido,
                "Telefono"=>$telefono,
                "Direccion"=>$direccion,
                "Email"=>$email,
                "Usuario"=>$usuario,
                "Clave"=>$clave,
                "Estado"=>"activa", 
                "Privilegio"=>$privilegio,
                "Rol"=>$rol
            ];

$agregar_usuario= usuarioModelo::agregar_usuario_modelo($datos_usuario_reg);

?>

Comment: Why is first line in your model function a return statement? Can you comment `return $datos;` in `agregar_usuario_modelo` then test?

Comment: sorry yes i do that to test what is receive from the controller but the data is ok. i am not understand why work fine i si call the model separate but when i call from the controller not work at all

Comment: Please try to handle exception to see it is not throwing any exception when called from controller.

Comment: i try but not trowing any exception only execute but not insert the data in the database

Comment: Do you think `conectar()` in `agregar_usuario_modelo` has right connection value when called from controller?
Also what `$sql` value does it return in controller?

Comment: hi yes conectar() has the right value because i test the model only with out the controller and insert the data without any problem, when i want to see what $sql has show this ; Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in C:\laragon\www\turnos_online\controladores\usuarioControlador.php on line 65

Comment: Can you add code which you use for testing in your question? Also can you call this function from controller with those same static values which you use in test and check?

Comment: i add the test code